# Обновление сущности в EF

Tags: .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Допустим, у меня есть некоторый репозиторий, который прячет за собой использование EF Core.

Т.е пользователь подал в Get какую-то id и получит сущность, которая при передаче наружу разумеется уже без какого-либо контекста.

Есть метод Set, который принимает на вход сущность. Это может быть, как ранее переданная сущность из метода Get, так и абсолютно новая сущность, которой еще нету в БД(он создал ее за пределами репозитория).

Если я правильно понимаю, то, если PK=0, то я могу ее со спокойной душой добавлять простой Add в контекст и сохраняться и EF все сам разрулит?

А вот как быть с обновлением? Я должен выбрать по ID запись из контекста и потом по полям выполнить обновление? И что будет, если я через Include, когда возвращаю из Get не сделаю загрузку виртуальных свойств? Получается, что при обновлении они очистятся, если они ранее были?

Answer (score 0):

> Если я правильно понимаю, то, если PK=0, то я могу ее со спокойной
>   душой добавлять простой Add в контекст и сохраняться и EF все сам
>   разрулит?

Да, можете спокойно добавлять сущность в контекст.

> А вот как быть с обновлением? Я должен выбрать по ID запись из
>   контекста и потом по полям выполнить обновление? И что будет, если я
>   через Include, когда возвращаю из Get не сделаю загрузку виртуальных
>   свойств? Получается, что при обновлении они очистятся, если они ранее
>   были?

Для обновления воспользуйтесь методом [Update](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.update?view=efcore-3.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbContext_Update_System_Object_). EF сам разберется, что нужно сделать с виртуальными свойствами. Очищаться эти свойства не должны.

Comment: Только вот на счет второго все таки не уверен. Как EF поймет очищал ли пользователь снаружи виртуальные свойства или сущность пришла без них, так как не было Include.

Comment: @iluxa1810 "A recursive search of the navigation properties will be performed to find reachable entities that are not already being tracked by the context. All entities found will be tracked by the context." По идее, это как раз говорит о том, что он определит, что зависимые сущности не были загружены и, значит, удалять их не надо.

Comment: Но контекста-то у меня нету на тот момент....

Comment: @iluxa1810, метод Set без контекста жить не может. О каком моменте тогда идет речь?

Comment: Не, я имею ввиду, что в Set создается новый контекст и что-то закрадываются подозрение, что он не сможет все разрулить.

Comment: @iluxa1810, ну подозрения можно проверить путем воспроизведения нужной ситуации. По описанию все выглядит нормально.